# How to show the Eclipse Move context menu in project explorer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, contextmenu

I have noticed that by default Eclipse "Move" context menu is not shown when a folder and a file is multi selected at once.

My scenario is i want to show the my context menu -Move for  certain type of files and folders when multi selected.

```
  <and>
                  <iterate
                      operator="or">
                <with
                   variable="org.eclipse.ui.selection">

                   <adapt
                         type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                      <or>
                         <test    property="com.sap.ndb.studio.dwb.team.ui.expressions.isContainedInSharedProject" value = "true"/>
                         <test property="com.sap.ndb.studio.dwb.team.ui.expressions.isFile"  value="true"/>
                         <test property="com.sap.ndb.studio.dwb.team.ui.expressions.isFolder"  value="true"/>
                      </or>
                   </adapt>

                 </with>
              </iterate>
</and>
```

How can i enable my context menu for the type folder and a file in multi select?

Regards,
Pavitra

Comment: Move shows for me with a ordinary folder and file, it does not show when a Java package folder is selected. This is presumably because different processing is required.

Comment: How to show a context menu for a multiple selection for different instances? like a file and a folder

Answer (score 0):

in `Project explorer`, select those files that you want to move,

right click on one of them, select `Refactor`, by default `Move...` option is available.
or simply you can use shortcut to move: `Alt+Shift+V`.

[image]

**if it wasn't enabled or doesn't exist**, in eclipse go to `Window` menu,
select `Customize perspective...`

[image]

a windows with for tabs will appear.
select `Menu visibility` tab then expand `Refactor`, then tic the `Move...` checkbox.

[image]